# -b:v above 9.8M for DVD-Video

Tags: ffmpeg, dvd, video-conversion, video-encoding, mpeg2

Details of Nache1080.mp4:-

- resolution=1920x1080
- fps=60
- Avg Video Bit Rate=11610 kbps
- duration=00:00:14
- size=19.6 MB

I produced mpeg2 video from this mp4 video using below command:

```
ffmpeg -i Nache1080.mp4 -c:v mpeg2video -s 720x576 -r 25 -b:v 20000k Nache_dvd_20000.mpg
```

Details of produced mpeg2 video namely Nache_dvd_20000.mpg:-

- min Video Bit Rate=3298 kbps
- max Video Bit Rate=5954 kbps
- avg Video Bit Rate=4675 kbps
- size=8.533 mb

The max video bit rate for DVD-Video is 9.8 MB. The max video bit rate of produced mpeg2 video is 5954 kbps. But I specified 20000k as input for video bit rate which is greater than 9.8 MB.

1. Will DVD-player be able to play this video? What problems `-b:v 20000k` will create for DVD-Player?
2. Will PAL-TV be able to display this video? What problems `-b:v 20000k` will create for PAL-TV?

The above command produced below warning on FFMPEG console:

> [mpeg @ 0000000000604c80] VBV buffer size not set, using default size
>   of 230KB If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some
>   specification Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct
>   buffer size

3. Will this warning cause any problems for DVD-Player and/or PAL-TV?

If I add `-target pal-dvd` to remove the warning FFMPEG generates below error and produces a mpeg2(or output) video having 0 bytes:

> F:ffmpeg-4.2-win64-static\bin>**ffmpeg -i Nache1080.mp4 -c:v mpeg2video
>   -s 720x576 -r 25 -b:v 20000k -target pal-dvd Nache_dvd_20000.mpg**
>   ffmpeg version 4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
>   built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
>    configuration: --enable-gpl
>   --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype -
>   -enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --en able-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-l ibvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid -- enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
>    libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100   
> libavcodec     58. 54.100 /
>   58. 54.100   
> libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100   
> libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100   
> libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100   
> libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100   
> libswresample   3.  5.100 / 
>   3.  5.100   
> libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100 
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Nache1080.mp4':   
> Metadata:
>       
> major_brand     : isom
>       
> minor_version   : 512
>       
> compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>       
> encoder         : Lavf57.56.100   
> Duration: 00:00:14.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11767 kb/s
>       
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 11623 kb/s, 60.07 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
>       
> Metadata:
>         
> handler_name    : VideoHandler
>       
> Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 171 kb/s (default)
>       
> Metadata:
>         
> handler_name    : SoundHandler 
> Stream mapping:   
> Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg2video (native))   
> Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> ac3 (native)) 
> Press [q] to stop, [?] for help 
> [mpeg2video
>   @ 0000000002f500c0] bitrate above max bitrate Error initializing
>   output stream 0:0 -- 
> Error while opening encoder for output stream
>
> ## 0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height 
> Conversion failed!

Comment: Please show the full, uncut command line output for the command that produces the error with `-target pal-dvd`.

Comment: @slhck Updated output of FFMPEG.

Comment: When I tried to replicate this issue it appeared that there are some issues with this command in ffmpeg 4.3.5-0+deb11u1. Per the documentation the target flag also defines the video buffer size, so this command is passing conflicting parameters. The dvd-pal type includes "-bufsize:v 1835008" (1835k).